# How do I access the dBase table that was automatically opended in dBASE8?

Tags: dbase

We recently bought dBASE 8 as a replacement for Visual dBASE which no longer works in Windows 7/8 64 bit. We don't plan using it for programming but just for simple manipulations of .dbf files, like adding or deleting columns, filtering and exporting etc.

After setting up dBASE 8 to be the default program for .dbf files, double clicking a .dbf file automatically opens and displays that table.

Visual DBase used to automatically add a line to the command window like

```
use "c:\some\dir\table.dbf"
```

and any command entered into that window would work on that table. This seems to be different with dBASE 8. The line above does not get added and if I enter a command that needs a table to be open, like

```
set filter to strasse="blablub"
```

I get the file open dialog.

Is there any way to get the "old" behavior back? Or is there any simple way to switch to the table that is already being displayed without having to type the name again or selecting it in the file open dialog?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ask dbase support?

Comment: You are right and I did. No answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got an [answer](http://news.dbase.com/newsgroups.php?art_group=dbase.getting-started&article_id=15630) in the dbase newsgroup that solves part of the problem

This program

```
**********************
* GrabBrowse.prg
* Catches the table that was opened in an instance of PLUS
*  by double-clicking on a table in Windows Explorer.
* Sets the query as _app.q.
* Reports the tablename.
* Returns the query.
* Opens the table with USE.

private q
q = findinstance("query")
? q.rowset.tablename
_app.q = q

if not empty(findinstance("query", q))
  msgbox("There is more than one query active:  ";
    + findinstance("query", q).rowset.tablename ;
    + chr(13) + "But still put in _app.q and USEd.", ;
    "GrabBrowse", 48)
endif

use (q.rowset.tablename)

return (q)
**********************
```

stored in a text file in the dBASE search path and called with

```
do GrabBrowse
```

switches to the table so any commands will affect that table.
e.g.

```
set filter to strasse="blablub"
```

will set the filter for that table. Unfortunately this does not affect the browse window that is already open but only one that is opened afterwards.

But it's a partial solution.